# Monitor black if displayport cable is connected

Tags: display, hdmi, displayport

I have a Dell u3011 monitor and I have been using a displayport cable for a few months until the screen suddenly turned black while I was using it. Since then I haven’t been able to get an image back using displayport. When I only have an hdmi cable connected everything works but at a lower resolution(1920x1200). If i was to connect the displayport cable the monitor turns black and doesn’t react(the buttons on the side do not work for a few minutes) when the monitor reacts again and I go back to the hdmi input source the screen still doesn’t work.

I do not know why anything of this happened, it happened out of nowhere and it is really frustrating to be using my screen at a lower resolution. Any help regarding this black screen is very much appreciated and if there  is anything you would need to know please do not hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 0):

A recent update or configuration may have occurred if it was working and now it is not.
Might be an issue with the acpi power distribution failing to provide enough juice, not recognizing the peripheral type correctly.  I would try installing the Monitor driver from Dell, and set the monitor to prioritize display port startup if available. I found the link to Dell here.

http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/dell-u3011/drivers

Also some monitors have an upstream/one way USB cable that is used to provide power for some features built into the monitor, such as USB port charging. This might help the power management pick up the DisplayPort connection. There are several ways to trouble shoot this. Let me know if you want to try some other steps if this does not work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and I do not think it is driver related as the monitor turned black whilst using it.

Comment: Drivers can malfunction for many reasons.

Comment: Try the Dell website and download the drivers for your monitor and research troubleshooting steps specific to the monitor model type.  Windows 10 does not always provide the best drivers for all systems automatically.  [Dell Support][http://www.dell.com/support/home/ed/en/edbsdt1/product-support/product/dell-u3011/drivers]